# Display alert in OnClick event if server-side validation fails

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

I have an ASP.NET page with an `OnClick` event defined on the Save button.  I want to implement behaviour like this:

```
protected void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Validate state on server side
    // ...
    if (isValid)
    {
        // Save the settings
    }
    else
    {
        // Display alert with error meessage
    }
}
```

As noted in the comments above, I need to perform some server-side validation of the state of the system.  If any errors occur, I need to display an alert dialog immediately (preferrably without reloading the page).

I have tried using `RegisterClientScriptBlock` and `RegisterStartupScript` to register some Javascript to run within the page, but it doesn't seem to do what I want.

It sounds like I need to put them in the `Page_Load` to that the Javascript registers up-front, but I also need to ensure that the error doesn't display if everything validates okay.  The problem is that if I register the alert into `Page_Load`, the alert will come up before we've had a chance to validate everything and see that everything is actually okay.

I figured that I could put a hidden field in the form that I can use as a flag to indicate whether things are valid, but the life-cycle of the page is doing my head in and I can't seem to figure out how to get this working properly.

What I really need is some sort of server-side validation event to kick in just before `SaveButton_Click` which can set the hidden form field indicating whether everything is okay, and then I can make my Javascript registered dependent on the value of this hidden field.

Is this possible?  Is there a better way?

Comment: "doesn't seem to do what I want" - really? Imagine somebody asks you a question describing the problem like this. `RegisterClientScriptBlock` or `RegisterStartupScript` are the tools to use. What did not work? Did you look at the page source (in the browser) to see if your javascript is there and has correct syntax?

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember where I found this little jem at, but I have an alert class that I can call from my code behind.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Alert
/// </summary>
public static class Alert
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Shows a client-side JavaScript alert in the browser.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message">The message to appear in the alert.</param>
    public static void Show(string message)
    {
        // Cleans the message to allow single quotation marks
        string cleanMessage = message.Replace("'", "\\'");
        string script = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('" + cleanMessage     + "');</script>";

        // Gets the executing web page
        Page page = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as Page;

        // Checks if the handler is a Page and that the script isn't allready on the Page
        if (page != null && !page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("alert"))
        {
            page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Alert), "alert", script);
        }
    }
    public static void Show(string message, string redirect)
    {
        // Cleans the message to allow single quotation marks
        string cleanMessage = message.Replace("'", "\\'");
        string script = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('" + cleanMessage + "');window.location.href='"+redirect+"'</script>";

        // Gets the executing web page
        Page page = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as Page;

        // Checks if the handler is a Page and that the script isn't allready on the Page
        if (page != null && !page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("alert"))
        {
            page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Alert), "alert", script);
        }
    }
}
```

Then called in as part of my try/catch statement as

```
    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    try
    {

        //blah blah, some data access suff


    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        Alert.Show(ex.Message);
    }
```